# What to keep in mind when copying a small card game?

Tags: playing-cards

There's an old card game I want, but it's been out of print for 15 years and currently going for >$1000 used. There are just 80 cards in the game, and I've got a friend who does own it.

My plan is just to scan the cards, print them two-sided, laminate them and cut them out with a knife. I could also get plastic pockets and print the front and back separately.

What are some common pitfalls in printing a card game, and what am I likely to have missed?

(Don't worry, of course I'll mail a fit donation to the manufacturers.)

Comment: I am not sure asking advice about potential copyright infringement is allowed on this website.

Comment: If you do not copy the actual cards (not using their images), it might not be illegal. (like magic workstation for MTG. and isotropic for dominion)

Comment: @ColinD It's honestly not clear that Isotropic and Magic Workstation are _legal_ as much as they are _tolerated_ - though I wholeheartedly agree with your first point.

Comment: I am very curious, what is the game?

Comment: @Andrey: It's Knightmare Chess (2). I did email SJG about permission to copy my friend's game, but for some reason they wouldn't allow it, even with economic compensation.

Comment: @Anna wow i have that somewhere.  There is right now a copy of it for 200 on ebay, the price is a little exaggerated.

Comment: @Andrey: Yeah. And I want to own it, but not _that_ badly.

Answer (score 5):

As commenters have pointed out, the copying that you are describing is illegal in most countries.

This isn't legal advice (and it depends on where you're located), but a quick Google search about copying and protecting card games seems to suggest [that you probably can make a copy](http://www.pagat.com/links/design.html) if you don't directly copy the artwork or wording used in the original game. It sounds like you can write out the rules in your own words, and make your own cards. Of course, some would say this is ethically questionable. And who knows what the issues are if the game mechanics are patented in some way.

> (Don't worry, of course I'll mail a fit donation to the manufacturers.)

There's a better way. If the game is out of print, but the manufacturers are still contactable, why not just write to them? You can avoid the issue of illegal copyright infringement if you have permission.

Something like "I am really interested in a copy of this game. Is it possible to buy it from you still? Are you likely to reprint it anytime soon? If not, would you mind if I photocopied my friends copy and mailed you $70?"

Comment: Does this answer the question? It sounds like the OP is asking for practical advice with printing and laminating cards, rather than copyright concerns.

Comment: I think it answers "what am I likely to have missed" :)

Comment: If you have any legal concerns about what you're doing, I would actually recommend _not_ sending the manufacturers money - it could easily be interpreted as an acknowledgement that you know what you're doing is in the legal wrong.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm not advocating sending them money in response to illegal infringement, I'm advocating asking them for legal permission to make a copy (and offering money).

Answer (score 5):

Copyright concerns aside, I can help with the printing. I recently made a 100-card game (actually a Fluxx variant) like so:

I printed out the cards in sheets of nine cards (onto standard A4 paper), then chopped them out with scissors. This might take a while if you've got too many, but 80 should be OK.

To make them more sturdy, I bought 100 penny-sleeves and got a bunch of old, unwanted Magic cards (try your FLGS or CCG-playing friends if you have none). I simply placed the printed cards (on paper) into a sleeve with a Magic card to make it firm and less vulnerable to breaking while shuffling/dealing/etc.

If the card-backs are significant (they weren't for me), you could print them out too and place them in the other side of the sleeve, but honestly that sounds like a lot of work. For instance, if there are two types of card, you could put some Magic cards in backwards, or use different CCGs, or different colours of Magic card.

Not particularly high-quality, but considering the cost is the cost of printing a dozen sheets of paper and about a quid for the sleeves, it's prototype-gaming on a budget!

Answer (score 4):

I have just built a prototype for a card game.  Since I was not using any art, I ordered the printing of the cards on those small business cards.  They are thick and sturdy enough to last a long while and easy to shuffle too.
The most of the card rules are common, so, not a lot of text needed to be on the cards them selves.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on a custom Fluxx deck, have done a little research, www.makeplayingcards.com has a lot of customization options. Not sure they are the cheapest (but you can order a single deck if you want, $12 for 54 cards), but was referred by a friend who says quality is good.

Johno, would be interested in comparing notes on custom Fluxx decks...